# returning const pointer to const int

Tags: c, pointers, parameters, constants

In this code:

```
const int* const fun(const int *const ptr)
{
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    int i=9;
    int *main_ptr;
    main_ptr = fun(&i);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler warns:

> warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
>        main_ptr = fun(&i);

On defining `main_ptr` as a pointer to `const int` the warning goes away (which is understandable) but compiler doesn't complain about discarding `const` qualifier while degrading from a `const` pointer to just a pointer.

Is this behavior of warning in one case and no warning in other because of the fact that when it come to pointer to `const int` in this case the variable being pointed is not destroyed when the function `fun` ends and due to the same reason the `const` pointer to `int` part doesn't matter as the variable is local and it gets destroyed when `fun` gets over?

Comment: "compiler doesn't complain about discarding `const` qualifier while degrading from a `const` pointer to `int` to a just a pointer to `int`." I don't understand what you mean.  Where does this happen where the compiler does not issue a warning?

Comment: You also talk about `const int`, but there is nothing of type `const int` in your code.

Comment: @jamesdlin Its **pointer** to `const int`, the compiler doesn't issue a warning/error when a `const` pointer is degraded to just a pointer.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus Function arguments are passed by value, so there is no chance for `fun` to modify `main_ptr`, and therefore there is no possible const violation to warn of. This has nothing to do with "*variable being pointed is not destroyed*", which I am not sure what even means in this context.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus The warning you cited *is* complaining that you're converting a `const T*` (pointer to `const`) to `T*`.  Or by "`const` pointer", do you mean a `T* const`?  That'd be no different from assigning a `const int` to an `int`.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus "*while degrading from a const pointer to just a pointer.*" - What and where shall be this "*degrading*" process you´re talking about? This doesn´t match to your provided code. Do you want us to pick in the dark? Please create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also, for the same reason, no warning in `int foo = /* (const) */ 42;`

Comment: `main_ptr = fun(&i);` is `main_ptr` const? You are attempting to assign and `const int *` to `int *` -- thus the warning `assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qualifiers (`const`, `volatile`, `restricted`, and `_Atomic`) apply only to lvalues (designators of objects in memory), not to values (data in expressions). Per C 2018 6.7.3 5:

> The properties associated with qualified types are meaningful only for expressions that are lvalues.

Consider `const int x = 3; int y = x;`. This is allowed. The `const` is a restriction on `x`. Once the value of `x` is read, the result is just the `int` 3; there is no `const` attached to the 3. Then we may set the value of `y` to 3, and there is no requirement that `y` not change after that. `const` does not stick with the value, and the compiler will not warn us about this.

The declaration `const int* const fun(const int *const ptr)` says the **value** returned by `fun` is `const`. That is meaningless, and a good compiler could warn that the `const` just before `fun` has no effect. Regardless, this qualifier is discarded when evaluating the function call, so there is no problem in assigning the return value of this function to a pointer that is not `const`.

We can consider a simpler example:

```
int t;
const int * const x = &t;
const int *       y = x;
```

The compiler does not warn about this because `y` receives only the value of `x`. The fact that `x` may not change does not impede our ability to assign its value to `y`, which can change.

### Supplement

When an lvalue is used for its value in an expression, all its qualifiers are discarded. C 2018 6.3.2.1 2 says:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the unary `&` operator, the `++` operator, the `--` operator, or the left operand of the `.` operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called lvalue conversion. If the lvalue has qualified type, the value has the unqualified version of the type of the lvalue; …

Each qualifier says something about how an **object in memory** will be treated:

- `const` says the object in memory will not be modified (through this lvalue).
- `volatile` says the object in memory can change by means unknown to the C implementation or that accessing it can cause effects unknown to the C compiler.
- `restrict` says the object in memory will only be accessed by means derived from that particular lvalue.
- `_Atomic` says accesses to the object in memory behave as if it were one indivisible thing (not made of bytes that can be read or modified separately), so that accesses from multiple threads always use a “whole” value for it, never mixing partial accesses from different threads.

Answer (score 0):

There are two type "mismatches" at play here, the first being

```
main_ptr = fun(...)    // const int *const -> int *
```

where we are discarding the `const`ness of the return value of `fun` by assigning it to `main_ptr`, and the second being

```
... = fun(&i)          // int * -> const int *const
```

where we are passing in a plain old `int *` into a function that takes a `const int *const`.

As you have noticed, you will be warned when performing the first one because we are losing a safety guarantee that the return type of `fun` made.

The second one is not an issue because we are gaining a safety guarantee during the execution of `fun` that the parameter is pointing to a constant integer. In reality, the parameter does not refer to a constant `int`, but there is no harm in adding more restrictive `const` qualifiers. There is danger in removing them, so you get a warning for the first situation.

Comment: The question is particularly about why the second `const` of `const int * const fun(const int *const ptr)` may be discarded. Essentially, it asks why `int t; const int * const x = &t; const int * y = x;` does not produce an error. This answer does not address that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for the clarification. At the time of my answer, it was difficult to determine what the question was asking. Also, where do you pull your C standard quotes from? Is there a searchable copy of the standard you know of?

Comment: I purchased a copy of the 2018 standard. Information about official and draft versions is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents).